# Why would cockroaches and other pests thrive in a hotel?

Tags: hotels, bed-bugs

Disclaimer: I have never been in a hotel. I'm not basing this on actual experiences.

I've generally got the idea and heard many stories or remarks about how hotels in various popular vacation countries often have bugs in the rooms. Like cockroaches. Spiders. Rats?

How can this be? With people constantly moving in and out and professional daily cleaning, how can any pests thrive in such a place?

I've had the disgusting spiders at home, way too many times, but never once a cockroach (but the odd rat). I don't even understand how it can possibly be dirty enough for a cockroach to actually live inside an apartment. Come to think of it, I'm not sure I've ever actually *seen* a cockroach at all in my entire life...

Is the bug situation vastly different in other places? That sounds nightmarish. Can it be all made up, like so many other factoids?

Comment: I do not think this is a travel question. I also think your starting point is not right. The bugs and pests do not seek out hotels. they just happen to be seen there some times. (And they may well be common pests in those areas. Just count yourself lucky that they are not common pests where you live.)

Comment: I suspect this perception could be based on some stereotypes about certain vacation destinations. If you're in an area with a lot of bugs, and especially if you're in a poor hotel that doesn't keep up on maintenance and pest control, the bugs will come inside the hotel. And regardless of the actual prevalence of bugs, the stereotype of a "fleabag motel" is a trope to denote low-quality lodging. And then you add in bedbugs, which are an inherent problem in a building full of shared beds.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about travel within the scope defined by the [help]. The supposed problem is far too broad a generalization, and demonstrates some general misapprehensions concerning vermin control that beg independent research effort.

Answer (score 1):

Bedbugs are hard to kill, especially if no one tells management they are there.  And if you stay somewhere that has them, they will soon be in everyplace else you stay unless you handle them properly.